# How to reorder nodes within a node using awesome_nested_set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-sets, acts-as-nested-set

If I have a tree like this:

```
Page1
---Page1.1
---Page1.2
---Page1.3
```

Using awesome_nested_set, how would I move Page1.x up or down within the Page1 node?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From http://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/blob/master/lib/awesome_nested_set.rb :

```
# Shorthand method for finding the left sibling and moving to the left of it.
def move_left
  move_to_left_of left_sibling
end

#Shorthand method for finding the right sibling and moving to the right of it.
def move_right
  move_to_right_of right_sibling
end

# Move the node to the left of another node (you can pass id only)
def move_to_left_of(node)
  move_to node, :left
end

# Move the node to the left of another node (you can pass id only)
def move_to_right_of(node)
  move_to node, :right
end
```